# NSFetchedResultsController in background via MagicalRecord

Tags: core-data, magicalrecord

How to use method MR_fetchAllSortedBy in background thread?

I tried so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadFetchedResultsController];
}

- (void)loadFetchedResultsController
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{
        _fetchedResultsController = [Podcast MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"position"
                              ascending:YES
                          withPredicate:nil
                                groupBy:nil
                               delegate:self]
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
            {
                 [MagicalRecord handleErrors:error];
            }
        });
    });
}
```

These seem loaded, but the UITableView is empty

Comment: The MR_fetch methods will perform the fetch prior to returning, so you're effectively fetching twice in this case. Are you noticing performance issues in your fetching or just curious? Either way, I'd start by choosing a batch size, and sending that through your fetch request prior to looking into background fetching.

Comment: I add [self.tableView reloadData] and now my code works. The difference in performance with work in background and main thread very noticeable